# MYSQL Select command into S3 bucket-error

Tags: mysql, amazon-s3

I am trying to run a select statement from MYSQL that queries a table for a few tables and then writes it to an S3 bucket as a CSV file. My code from my MYSQL console goes like this:

```
select * from table_name INTO OUTFILE  S3 's://mybucketpath/table1.csv
credentials 'myawscredentials'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
overwrite on;
```

When I run this, I get the following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'myawscredntials' FIELDS' at line 1
```

Any way to run this query using my AWS credentials?

Any suggestions or ideas would help.

Thanks.

Comment: it's not possible for that query to generate that error message

Comment: the 's://mybucketpath/table1.csv' should be into quotes

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a valid query:

```
SELECT columns
     , you 
     , actually 
     , want INTO OUTFILE 's://mybucketpath/table1.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
  FROM credentials ;
```

Comment: i think he is using aws https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_en/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/AuroraMySQL.Integrating.SaveIntoS3.html

Comment: @nbk Could be, in which case this answer isn't relevant.